# How to track users that came from specific push notification and made a purchase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, usage-statistics

I'm setting up statistics for Android app and I'm not sure what statistics tools should I use. I was looking to use Firebase\Google Analytics, but they have lots of different tools and I'm not sure which (if any) to use.

My main requirement for statistics is an ability to track number of users that make a purchase after specific promo event.

For example:

1. Push notification is sent to all app users.
2. Some users opened the app using push 
   notification (Event A with pushId as parameter)
3. Some users made a purchase (Event B with productId as parameter)
4. X users had EventA with pushId=PUSH-X 
   and also had EventB with productId=PRODUCT-X.
5. What tools and events should I use to be able to find X in statistics?
6. It would be also useful to know how many users had EventA with pushId=PUSH-X 
   and EventB with productId=PRODUCT-X during the same user session.

Google analytics has a tool that looks to be related: funnels.
But it seems that it cannot filter specific push id and product id and connect the two. I can only find number of all users who opened the app with a push at some time and then made some purchase some time later.
Is there a way to filter events by parameters?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that a sequence segment would work for you. You may construct a segment where a first step is an event and some of the next is a transaction with a specified product.

[Here is](https://www.getelevar.com/analytics/how-to-use-custom-sequence-segments-in-google-analytics/) some overview of sequence segments